# How do I loop through an array and do mysql real escape on all enities?

Tags: php, post, mysqli

I would like to do mysql real escape on all my posted forms found in the $_POST[] array. But I don't know how to loop through the array to escape every string.

I have different names like, serverAddressIn and serverPortOut that I need to "secure" before inserting them into the database.

How can I loop through my array and secure my form posts?

Comment: `$_POST` is already array.

Comment: It should be `$_POST['blah']['sub']`, now you have nested array, which you can loop using foreach

Comment: Use parameterised queries instead.

Comment: Stackoverflow is scary over populated by users if you are used to Ask Ubuntu...

Comment: An update didn't make it any better.

Answer (score 2):

Sample `form`, `escape` and `query`

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="options[name]" />
    <input name="options[city]" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['options']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['options'] as $key => $value) 
        {
            $options[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($options))."`) VALUES ('".implode("', '", $options)."')";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Either approach and implementation here are flawed. Even with silly error fixed, this code does encourage manual string formatting which is a big no-no and ought to be discarded in favor of using **placeholders**. It's a shame to see this answer upvoted.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What's the issue?

Comment: Dont be! If my answer flawed, explain to me why? I used `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Why `vulnerable to SQL injection`? Really my answer not useful, i'll delete

Comment: This is a clear example showing you why manual escaping is bad, It made you warm feeling of security - "I used mysqli_real_escape_string", in the meaning of "I have my query protected!". This is why you have to use a **placeholder** for the ANY dynamical part of your query. And this is why a BIG RED banner have to flash on you if you are unable to use a placeholder for some dynamical part of your query.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to mysqli_real_escape on all inputs before I handle them.

Nope, you don't.

> to clean the strings

"mysqli_real_escape" **doesn't "clean" anything.**

> Is there a better way

Sure. You have to use prepared statements. And, some sort of abstraction library to do all the dirty job for you. Here is an example using [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):

```
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new safeMysql();

$allowed = array('server', 'serverAddress', 'serverportIN', 'serverAddressOut');
$data    = $db->filterArray($_POST, $allowed);
$sql     = "INSERT INTO ?n SET ?u";
$db->query($sql, $table, $data);
```

as simple as that.

Note that you ought to make an explicit **white list** of your field names due to security reasons

Comment: @Alvar He does not explain things, he just likes to downvote only. Look at his downvote rate. **12,656** downvotes vs **2,371 upvotes**